# Django custom login page condition not working

Tags: django, django-views

I have 2 login page - `login_admin` and `login_user` for admin and normal user respectively.

When user enter username and password in `login_admin` and `login_user` page, it will check whether user `is_staff` is `True` or `False`.
If user is_staff = True, then allow the user login admin page.

My problem is: The user can't login to admin page although `is_staff = True`. The user is able to login to normal user page although `is_staff = True`. I don't know where is the problem.

Here is my code in views.py:

```
def login_admin(request):
    context = {}
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        if username and password:
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            if user:
                if request.user.is_staff:
                    login(request, user)
                    return redirect('/home/')
                else:
                    context['error'] = "You are authenticated but are not authorized to access this page. Would you like to login to a different account?"
                    return render(request, 'registration/login.html',context)
            else:
                context['error'] = "Invalid username or password!"
                return render(request, 'registration/login.html',context)
    return render(request, 'registration/login.html')

def login_user(request):
    context = {}
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        if username and password:
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            if user:
                if not request.user.is_staff:
                    login(request, user)
                    return redirect('/cust/home/')
                else:
                    context['error'] = "Invalid username or password!"
                    return render(request, 'registration/custlogin.html',context)
            else:
                context['error'] = "Invalid username or password!"
                return render(request, 'registration/custlogin.html',context)
    return render(request, 'registration/custlogin.html')
```

login.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %}Login{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<h2>Admin Login Screen</h2>
<a href="{% url 'login_user' %}">Customer Login Page</a>
<form method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <table cellpadding="10">
      <tr>
          <td><label for="usename">Username: </label></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="username" id="username" required></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td><label for="password">Password: </label></td>
          <td><input type="password" name="password" id="password" required></td>
      </tr>
      <p style="color:red; font-weight: bold">{{ error }}</p>
  </table>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

url.py

```
url(r'accounts/login/', customers.views.login_admin,name='login_admin'),
url(r'accounts/custlogin/', customers.views.login_user,name='login_user'),
url(r'accounts/logout/', customers.views.logout_user,name='logout_user'),
```

**UPDATED:**

I'm not able to sign in to admin page when is_staff = True / False which will return error `You are authenticated but are not authorized to access this page. Would you like to login to a different account?` which is written in my code, but able to sign in to user page when is_staff=True / False.
If i remove `if user.is_staff`, it works for admin and normal user.

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^accounts/login/$', customers.views.login_admin,name='login_admin'),
url(r'^accounts/custlogin/$', customers.views.login_user,name='login_user'),
url(r'^accounts/logout/$', customers.views.logout_user,name='logout_user'),
```

**UPDATED V2:**

I've tried the code that written by @Rarblack but still get error : `'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'is_staff'`.

So I've modified the code and it works.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        if username and password:
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            if user:
                            user_instance = User.objects.filter(Q(username_exact=username) & Q(is_staff=True))
                if user_instance:
                    login(request, user)
                    return redirect('/home/')
                else:
                     ....
```

Comment: If you are using `url()`, then you should use `^` and `$` to mark the beginning and the end of the url (e.g. `r'^accounts/login/$'`) to avoid unexpected behaviour. If you are using Django 2.0+, then you may prefer to switch to `path()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As seen from your code you are getting password and username from the login form and your implementation of it is not correct. You should have used django form or ModelForm and get the input from `cleaned_data` dict. It should have been something like this:

```
 if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ExampleForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data['username']
            password = form.cleaned_data'password']
            if username and password:
                user = authenticate(username=username, password=password) 
                ......
```

When we come to your issue, the problem is in this part:

```
if not request.user.is_staff:
                    login(request, user)
                    return redirect('/cust/home/')
```

what you are basically is doing letting non-staff users in. Change it to:

```
if request.user.is_staff:
                    login(request, user)
                    return redirect('/cust/home/')
```

**EIDT:** You are missing request part in the `authenticate()` method also try this:

```
user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
            if user:
                if not user.is_staff:
```

The problem is that you cannot check any user's staff status because at that time there is no any user logged in to check. So request.user will not return a user. But you can try this:

```
from django.contrib.models import User
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404


if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        if username and password:
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            if user:
                            user_instance = User.objects.filter(username_exact=username)
                if user_instance.is_staff:
                    login(request, user)
                    return redirect('/home/')
                else:
                     ....
```

Comment: It still doesn’t work after take off the ‘not’. Non-staff user still can login to that page after the first login is attempted. First login attempted when user.is_staff=True. Second try the login does work with user.is_staff=False too.

Comment: It still doesn't work as expected. Do I need to create django form? I thought that the django-form only to display in django admin site?

Comment: No, django form is for everywhere and it is the right way to follow

Comment: No, Django form is for everywhere and it is the right way to follow. But in this case, if you want you can skip it because you are not writing anything to the database.

Comment: thanks for the information. But is there any solution to solve this? Seems like the data in ‘is_staff’ cannot read by the system I think.

Comment: The problem is that you cannot check any user's staff status because at that time there is no any user loged in to check. So request.user will not return a user.

Comment: @Evon I updated the answer adn assuming that it will work. Good luck!!

Comment: thanks for help. I tried to add in your answer `user_instance = User.objects.filter(username_exact=username)`, it return this error `'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'is_staff'`. I don't know why but then I've edited the code to `user_instance = User.objects.all().filter(Q(username__exact=username) & Q(is_staff=True))`, and it works!

Comment: Maybe because of the django version not queite sure but glad you managed to solve the issue)

Answer (score 0):

You use `if not request.user.is_staff:` in both views. For `login_admin`, if you only want staff to be able to log in, you should change it to:

```
if request.user.is_staff:
```

Comment: It still doesn’t work. First login attempts is work only when user.is_staff=True. After the first login is attempt then I logout to having second try. Second try the login does work with user.is_staff=False too.

Comment: Make sure that your forms are being submitted to the correct urls. `registration/custlogin.html` should submit the form to `{% url 'login_user' %}`, and `registration/login.html` should submit the form to `{% url 'login_admin' %}`.

Comment: Yes, the forms submitted to correct urls. I don’t know why the form only sometimes work.